# ng-init or ng-bind does not work for sample code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-init, angularjs-bootstrap

My code:

Its simple but i don't get want am i missing:

```
<div ng-app="sample" ng-init="firstName='somnath'">
    <p>My name is: <span ng-bind="firstName"></span> 
    </p>
</div>
```

[Jsfiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/somnath_k/cbckn6ap/)

Comment: added angular js script?

Comment: yes  you can see in jsfiddle.when i type in textbox its types in h1

Comment: You need to learn https://angularjs.org/ document

Comment: i know am new to angular js so am here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing  two `ng-app` on same page will not work, Always 1st one is read by angular. you need to use `angular.bootstrap` to initialize angular on two elements.

**Markup**

```
<div id="app">
    <p>Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
    </p>
    <h1 ng-bind="name" />
</div>
<div id="app1" ng-init="firstName='somnath'">
    <p>My name is: <span ng-bind="firstName"></span> 
    </p>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
var app = angular.module('app',[])
var app1 = angular.module('app1',[])

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('app'), ['app']);
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('app1'), ['app1']);
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cbckn6ap/2/)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_intro_directives please tell me how it works here.thanks for answering

Comment: @SomnathKharat it works because they have only one `ng-app` with no module

Comment: @SomnathKharat yes it is, the one I've given is more advance

Answer (score 1):

This code is different but you can see how it works, you can;t display

```
<div ng-app="sample" ng-init="firstName='somnath'">
    <p>My name is: <span ng-bind="firstName"></span> 
    </p>
</div>
```

You need to assign firstName to ng-model (Example ng-model="firstname"), then only it will be considered as the property otherwise not recognize so it can't be displayed.

```
 <div ng-app="" ng-init="name='somnath'" >
        <p>Name:
            <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
        </p>

    <p>
       My name is:<span ng-bind="name"></span> 
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: `ng-modal` :o do you want to say `ng-model`?